# Changing the hue of texture image

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Is there a way to change the hue of texture image through composition and then saving out the image?

**Added this information**
Hmm, let me elaborate abit of the issue i'm facing. Currently i'm using texture painting inside blender to output the diffuse texture. So after i'm done painting, i wanted to adjust the hue of this texture so that i can see the end result on my model. I have a feeling its something to do with the texture node under compositing but i have no idea how to set it up. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Here is a video showing how to use masks in the compositor as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSZGruW5z4g

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely do a lot of editing in the compositor and then save the results, and then reload in as a new texture. Here in this simple example I am using the Compositor window and bringing my painting in that is show in the lower right hand uv image editor in it's first state in monotone value. I use an Image Node to bring it into the compositor, and then direct it to a Viewer node for output, using the Backdrop to see it there. In the lower left uv image editor, you can see I have chosen 'Viewer' output to see the same as the backdrop, and that is where the result can be saved by choosing 'Save Image As' from the Image options in the header. I have used a simple Color Mix node set to 'Color' and chosen a light blue and not so full strength. You can use all kinds of filters and correction nodes to edit your images there. Just don't confuse the Viewer node with the Composite output node - the viewer is what you need to send the output to the image editor.[image: Leis recolored]

Comment: Hmm, let me elaborate abit of the issue i'm facing. Currently i'm using texture painting inside blender to output the diffuse texture. So after i'm done painting, i wanted to adjust the hue of this texture so that i can see the end result on my model. I have a feeling its something to do with the texture node under compositing but i have no idea how to set it up. Any ideas?

Comment: Your texture is just an image -  so doing the editing like I set up is actually the way you would do it - but you cannot hook the compositor output to the material texture stack itself(Oh I wish this was possible) BUT.....

Comment: I did a little looking the other night and found that under the Color tab in the Texture panel, you can adjust the RGB components of the texture as well as the contrast and saturation. I made a demo video explaining it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQTSwrXMez4. I also think you can import the texture as a plane and match to camera and render the adjustment as well as see it in view on the model.